# Who use NgFor in my case?

Tags: java, php, html, angular

i have a list of horse race result in my database.
In my database, i have 3 table :
horse (cheval in french) with : id, name ...
race (course in french) with : id, name ...
and resultrace (resultatcourse in french) the id of the horse (cheval) and the id of the race (course) and position in the race(first, second ...)

When i want to use it in a NgFor to do a list of all my race, who can i can use only the race's name, the horse's name and his position ?

My JSON:

```
[
    {id: 1, nom: "Valdack", place: 2, course: 1},
    {id: 5, nom: "Flying fox", place: 1, course: 1},
    {id: 17, nom: "Dane Dream", place: 4, course: 1}
]
```

My html code :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; ">
     <h2>{{ item.nom (name of the race) }} | {{ item.nom (name of the horse) }} | N°{{ item.place }} </h2>   
  </ion-item>
```

My php :

```
try {
      $stmt     = $pdo->query('SELECT course.id, course.nom , cheval.id, cheval.nom , resultatcourse.place, resultatcourse.course, resultatcourse.place FROM course, cheval, resultatcourse WHERE resultatcourse.course = course.id AND resultatcourse.cheval = cheval.id');
      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         // Assign each row of data to associative array
         $data[] = $row;
      }

      // Return data as JSON
      echo json_encode($data);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

And my java :

```
load() : void
   {
       this.http.get('http://localhost/wequida/retrieve-resultatcourse.php').subscribe((data : any) =>
      {
         console.dir(data);
         this.items = data;
      },
      (error : any) =>
      {
         console.dir(error);
      });
   }
```

My table horse and my table race have 2 same columns : id and name, maybe it's the problem ?

Comment: Can you please add the JSON you're iterating over in your question please?

Comment: {id: 1, nom: "Valdack", place: 2, course: 1}
1
:
{id: 5, nom: "Flying fox", place: 1, course: 1}
2
:
{id: 17, nom: "Dane Dream", place: 4, course: 1}

Comment: I've added it into the question for you. From your HTML, it seems you're expecting the horse's name, and the race name, but there is only name field in your JSON...

Comment: I don't know why because on my request i take the name of the race and the name of the horse :(

Comment: Well you can only have one field called "nom", otherwise you can't differentiate between them. Maybe try calling one `horseName`, and one `raceName`?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution ! (Thk user184994 !)

In my php :

```
try {
      $stmt     = $pdo->query('SELECT course.id, course.nom as coursenom, cheval.id, cheval.nom as chevalnom, resultatcourse.place, resultatcourse.course, resultatcourse.place FROM course, cheval, resultatcourse WHERE resultatcourse.course = course.id AND resultatcourse.cheval = cheval.id');
      while($row  = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ))
      {
         // Assign each row of data to associative array
         $data[] = $row;
      }

      // Return data as JSON
      echo json_encode($data);
   }
   catch(PDOException $e)
   {
      echo $e->getMessage();
   }
```

I had an as to differentiate horse's name and race's name

In my html :

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of items; ">
     <h2>{{ item.coursenom }} | {{ item.chevalnom }} | N°{{ item.place }} </h2>
</ion-icon></button>
  </ion-item>
```

I use the as name